# How to simplify nested object using Zod.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, zod

I'm new to using zod.js, and I find that the `DataSchema` helps me check the API data types and simplify the API response directly.

However, I'm wondering if I can simplify the data like `myExpectedData` from zod component directly (without array map method)?

Here is my short sample code:

```
const apiUrl = 'https://api.jikan.moe/v4/top/anime';

const DataSchema = z.array(
    z.object({
        mal_id: z.number().nullable(),
        images: z.object({
            jpg: z.object({
                    image_url: z.string().nullable()
                }

            )
        })
    })
)

type DataSchema = z.infer < typeof DataSchema > ;

async function fetchTopAnime() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(apiUrl);
        const rawData = response.data
        const AnimeData = DataSchema.parse(rawData.data)

        const myExpectedData = AnimeData.map((el) => {
            return {
                ...el,
                images: el.images.jpg.image_url
            }
        })

        console.log(myExpectedData);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error fetching data: ${error}`);
    }
}

fetchTopAnime();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Zod's `transform` method](https://zod.dev/?id=transform):

> To transform data after parsing, use the `transform` method.
>
> ```
> const stringToNumber = z.string().transform((val) => val.length);
>
> stringToNumber.parse("string"); // => 6
> ```
>
> [...]

In your case:

```
const DataSchema = z.array(
  z.object({
    mal_id: z.number().nullable(),
    images: z
      .object({
        jpg: z.object({
          image_url: z.string().nullable(),
        }),
      })
      .transform((images) => images.jpg.image_url),
  })
)
```

You could alternatively transform the "item" object like so:

```
const DataSchema = z.array(
  z
    .object({
      mal_id: z.number().nullable(),
      images: z.object({
        jpg: z.object({
          image_url: z.string().nullable(),
        }),
      }),
    })
    .transform((item) => ({
      ...item,
      images: item.images.jpg.image_url,
    }))
)
```

...or even the array of items:

```
const DataSchema = z
  .array(
    z.object({
      mal_id: z.number().nullable(),
      images: z.object({
        jpg: z.object({
          image_url: z.string().nullable(),
        }),
      }),
    })
  )
  .transform((items) =>
    items.map((item) => ({
      ...item,
      images: item.images.jpg.image_url,
    }))
  )
```

...but I find it clearer to do transformations as close to the fields they apply to as possible. So I'd pick the first option.

(Or actually, if there's always max 1 image, I'd pick the second option and rename the field from `images` to e.g. `image`:

```
const DataSchema = z.array(
  z
    .object({
      mal_id: z.number().nullable(),
      images: z.object({
        jpg: z.object({
          image_url: z.string().nullable(),
        }),
      }),
    })
    .transform((item) => ({
      mal_id: item.mal_id,
      image: item.images.jpg.image_url,
    }))
)
```

But I digress.)